# Mongodb: update element in array with array values

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

This is the document in collection
i want to update edits array with guid as filter and update type with respect to guid as given.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6903ea4d2df0c5659334e763"),
    "Edits" : [ 
        {
            "Guid" : LUUID("accc4be7-7585-5e46-a639-52f0537895d8"),
            "Type" : change
        },
        {
            "Guid" : LUUID("aghc4be7-7585-5e46-a639-52f0537895h7"),
            "Type" : Remove
        }
    ]
}
```

Input:

```
Edits: [{"Guid":"accc4be7-7585-5e46-a639-52f0537895d8", "Type": "Completed"},{"Guid":"aghc4be7-7585-5e46-a639-52f0537895h7", "Type": "Done"} ]
```

output expected:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6903ea4d2df0c5659334e763"),
    "Edits" : [ 
        {
            "Guid" : LUUID("accc4be7-7585-5e46-a639-52f0537895d8"),
            "Type" : completed
        },
        {
            "Guid" : LUUID("aghc4be7-7585-5e46-a639-52f0537895h7"),
            "Type" : Done
        }
    ]
}
```

Please frame the query to update like this??

Comment: I think you need to go with looping only, cannot update collections with input.

Answer (score 0):

watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRXjJRJ03_A) video about deferent array update scenarios

in your case it's

```
Edits: [{"Guid":"accc4be7-7585-5e46-a639-52f0537895d8", "Type": "Completed"},{"Guid":"aghc4be7-7585-5e46-a639-52f0537895h7", "Type": "Done"} ]

collection.update(
 {
   _id: "6903ea4d2df0c5659334e763"
 },
 {
   $set: { "Edits": Edits}
 }
)
```